# Download image or webpage with image from PHP webpage

Tags: php, bash, image, curl, wget

I'm currently trying to write a bash script to allow for a user to enter text for a barcode they need printing (type C128) and then either:

- download the webpage with the barcode image or just the image, then print it locally
- print the remote URL page with the text they enter as a read variable for the URL to print

This is the site in particular:

https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=TEST1&style=165&type=C128B&width=388&height=150&xres=2&font=5

Replace TEST1 with any text.

I've tried using wget, curl, html2ps, html2ps + ps2pdf but I am running into an issue which originates from the base of the URL page:

https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php

Via CLI I get this:

"Need bar code type ex. C39"

The aim is to print the image locally or save it then print it.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -ne "Enter the ID you want to print: "
read locid

#html2ps https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=LOCATION$locid&style=165&type=C128B&width=388&height=150&xres=2&font=5 | lpr

#html2ps https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=LOCATION$locid&style=165&type=C128B&width=388&height=150&xres=2&font=5 | ps2pdf - /home/byron/locations/LOCATION$locid.pdf

#html2ps https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=LOCATION$locid&style=165&type=C128B&width=388&height=150&xres=2&font=5 -o /home/byron/locations/LOCATION$locid.html
#ps2pdf /home/byron/locations/LOCATION$locid.html /home/byron/locations/LOCATION$locid.pdf

lpr /home/byron/locations/LOCATION$locid.pdf
```

When using any CLI tools I seem to be getting an empty file or stdout output. Additionally the printing job gets immediately cancelled and shows "(stdin) to printer".

I tried https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168569/printing-webpage-using-browser-via-cli as above but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to use `LOCATION$locid` and not just `$locid`?

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "enter LocationID:" locid

wget -O $locid.gif "https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=$locid&style=165&type=C128B&width=388&height=150&xres=2&font=5"
```

Successfully downloaded the image called `test1`

[image]

Comment: I am using the word LOCATION before my variable as the barcode scanner needs that word before the variable :)

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution, looks like I just needed to surround my wget with double quotes and then provide a filename :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like barcodesinc.com no longer supports hotlinking: only pages on its own domain can use, open or create the barcode images...

I would suggest to use a different barcode image server. For example, I just found [a10.selenode.com](http://a10.selenode.com/):

`wget`"https://a10.selenode.com/code128/TEST1"
[image: TEST1 barcode]